# How to change color button (submit) after click close on modals bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

How to change button color submit after i click close button on modals.

when first pressing the button will change its color and appear modals. but when I close the close button in modals the first button does not change the color to the origin.

tell me how to change the color when I press the close button

My Code :

```js
//this code for change color after click
var b1 = document.getElementById("send");
var buttonClicked = false;
b1.onclick = function() {
  buttonClicked = !buttonClicked;
  if(buttonClicked === true){
    b1.style.backgroundColor = "#F47321";  
  }else{
    b1.style.backgroundColor = "#807874";  
  }
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="send" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block" data-toggle="modal" style="background-color: #807874" data-target="#myModal"><font color="white">CLICK ME</font></button>
<div id="modals">
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog" required>
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <!-- konten modal-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <!-- heading modal -->
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Syarat & Ketentuan</h4>
        </div>
        <!-- body modal -->
        <div class="modal-body" style="height:250px;width:auto;overflow:auto;padding:2%">
  <div id="toss">
   <script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
$( "#toss" ).load( "tos.html" );
});
</script>
</div>
        </div>
        <!-- footer modal -->
        <div class="modal-footer">
   
  <div align="left">
  <label class="checkbox-inline">
  <input type="checkbox" id="check" title="Please agree to our policy!" name="checkbox" />Saya setuju dengan syarat & ketentuan
  </label>&nbsp;
  <br>
  &nbsp;<p><label class="label label-danger">*Silahkan ceklis setuju untuk melanjutkan</label></p>
  </div>
 
          <button type="button" id="close" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="btncheck" value="Send" />
       
  </p></font>
    </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

 <script>
$(function() {
  var chk = $('#check');
  var btn = $('#btncheck');

  chk.on('change', function() {
    btn.prop("disabled", !this.checked);//true: disabled, false: enabled
  }).trigger('change'); //page load trigger event
});
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `on()` method `and shown/hidden` [modal classes](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_modal.asp) to detect when is it opened or closed. I have made next changes to your code:
**1)**  Added 2 new classes, one for each color you need, so when you use [toggleClass()](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_toggleclass.asp) jquery method you toggle beetween `addClass` and `removeClass` to plays with color classes.
**2)**`Button #send`: Added the class with grey color, instead of style attribute with `background-color`. Also removed `btn-default` wich gives you a default color you dont need.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myModal").on("shown.bs.modal", function () { 
        $("#send").toggleClass("grey orange")
    });
    $("#myModal").on("hidden.bs.modal", function () { 
        $("#send").toggleClass("grey orange")
    });
});
```

```css
.orange{
  background-color: #F47321;
}
.grey{
  background-color: #807874;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="send" class="btn btn-lg btn-block grey" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><font color="white">CLICK ME</font></button>
<div id="modals">
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog" required>
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <!-- konten modal-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <!-- heading modal -->
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Syarat & Ketentuan</h4>
        </div>
        <!-- body modal -->
        <div class="modal-body" style="height:250px;width:auto;overflow:auto;padding:2%">
  <div id="toss">
   <script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
$( "#toss" ).load( "tos.html" );
});
</script>
</div>
        </div>
        <!-- footer modal -->
        <div class="modal-footer">
   
  <div align="left">
  <label class="checkbox-inline">
  <input type="checkbox" id="check" title="Please agree to our policy!" name="checkbox" />Saya setuju dengan syarat & ketentuan
  </label>&nbsp;
  <br>
  &nbsp;<p><label class="label label-danger">*Silahkan ceklis setuju untuk melanjutkan</label></p>
  </div>
 
          <button type="button" id="close" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="btncheck" value="Send" />
       
  </p></font>
    </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

 <script>
$(function() {
  var chk = $('#check');
  var btn = $('#btncheck');

  chk.on('change', function() {
    btn.prop("disabled", !this.checked);//true: disabled, false: enabled
  }).trigger('change'); //page load trigger event
});
 </script>
```

Comment: Thanks it's work for me :) . can you explain it? what changed?

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
//this code for change color after click
var b1 = document.getElementById("send");
b1.onclick = function() {
  buttonClicked = !buttonClicked;
    b1.style.backgroundColor = "#F47321";  
}


var x = document.getElementsByClassName("close");
x.onclick = function() {
    b1.style.backgroundColor = "#807874";
}
```

Comment: the buttons do not change color

Comment: @Anggialansori, Updated my answer. Try this out, please.

Comment: when I press the close button the result just does not change the color of the previous button

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could be fine with jquery , you have it added.

```
  //this capture de close modal event
  $("#myModal").on("hidden.bs.modal", function () {
   $("#send").css("background-color", "#807874");
});

$("#send").on("click", function(){
  $("#send").css("background-color", "#F47321");
})
```

Comment: this have to be between two tags <script></script> is javascript code

Comment: replace your javascript code for this, say me if it works :)

Answer (score 0):

Have a default color defined for your button in the styles.
When button is clicked you can add a class to the button, which changes its color, and when modal is closed you can remove the class which changed its color.

Bootstrap has special events made for modal close `hidden.bs.modal` which triggers when the modal is successfully closed. You can listen to that event and remove that class when it is triggered.

```js
//this code for change color after click
var b1 = document.getElementById("send");


b1.onclick = function() {
  // whenever button is clicked add a class to the button, which overwrites the style
  $(b1).addClass("btn-modal-open");
}

$("#myModal").on("hidden.bs.modal", function(){
  // Attach event to the modal close, and when the modal is closed remove the class which overwrites background color
  $(b1).removeClass('btn-modal-open');
});
```

```css
#send{
  background: #807874;
}

.btn-modal-open{
  background: #F47321 !important;;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="send" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block" data-toggle="modal"  data-target="#myModal"><font color="white">CLICK ME</font></button>
<div id="modals">
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog" required>
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <!-- konten modal-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <!-- heading modal -->
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Syarat & Ketentuan</h4>
        </div>
        <!-- body modal -->
        <div class="modal-body" style="height:250px;width:auto;overflow:auto;padding:2%">
  <div id="toss">
   <script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
$( "#toss" ).load( "tos.html" );
});
</script>
</div>
        </div>
        <!-- footer modal -->
        <div class="modal-footer">
   
  <div align="left">
  <label class="checkbox-inline">
  <input type="checkbox" id="check" title="Please agree to our policy!" name="checkbox" />Saya setuju dengan syarat & ketentuan
  </label>&nbsp;
  <br>
  &nbsp;<p><label class="label label-danger">*Silahkan ceklis setuju untuk melanjutkan</label></p>
  </div>
 
          <button type="button" id="close" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="btncheck" value="Send" />
       
  </p></font>
    </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

 <script>
$(function() {
  var chk = $('#check');
  var btn = $('#btncheck');

  chk.on('change', function() {
    btn.prop("disabled", !this.checked);//true: disabled, false: enabled
  }).trigger('change'); //page load trigger event
});
 </script>
```

Comment: full code pls , when entering code into my codes does not work. strange

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" id="model-cross" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Syarat & Ketentuan</h4>
        </div>
```

Javascript Code :

```
 <script>
    var x = document.getElementById('modal-cross');
    x.onclick = function() { 
    b1.style.backgroundColor = "#807874";
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#modals').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
$(".btn-block").css("background-color",'#807874');
})
```

Add the above code. Once we click on close button, it will change the "click me" button color.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working snippet where I tried not to change too much your code:

```js
var b1 = document.getElementById("send");
b1.onclick = function() {
  b1.style.backgroundColor = "#F47321";
}

$('#modals').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
  b1.style.backgroundColor = '#807874';
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="send" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block" data-toggle="modal" style="background-color: #807874" data-target="#myModal"><font color="white">CLICK ME</font></button>
<div id="modals">
  <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog" required>
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <!-- konten modal-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <!-- heading modal -->
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Syarat & Ketentuan</h4>
        </div>
        <!-- body modal -->
        <div class="modal-body" style="height:250px;width:auto;overflow:auto;padding:2%">
          <div id="toss">
            <script type='text/javascript'>
              $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#toss").load("tos.html");
              });
            </script>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- footer modal -->
        <div class="modal-footer">

          <div align="left">
            <label class="checkbox-inline">
  <input type="checkbox" id="check" title="Please agree to our policy!" name="checkbox" />Saya setuju dengan syarat & ketentuan
  </label>&nbsp;
            <br> &nbsp;
            <p><label class="label label-danger">*Silahkan ceklis setuju untuk melanjutkan</label></p>
          </div>

          <button type="button" id="close" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="btncheck" value="Send" />

          </p>
          </font>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  $(function() {
    var chk = $('#check');
    var btn = $('#btncheck');

    chk.on('change', function() {
      btn.prop("disabled", !this.checked); //true: disabled, false: enabled
    }).trigger('change'); //page load trigger event
  });
</script>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: work on the snippet, but it did not work when I applied it. but thanks for helping